# Integrating AngularJS and tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, angularjs

See: http://jsbin.com/udayah/2/edit

Modifying the datamodel associated with the tinyMCE textarea throws a Javascript error:

"$digest already in progress"

<strike>In my app, unlike the JS Bin example, the text in tinyMCE does not change when I change the associated datamodel and the same error is thrown.  I am using a couple other AngularUI directives, Codemirror and JQueryUI Dialogs, which may be complicating the issue.</strike>

Comment: You'll have to view the Javascript Console to see the error pop up.

Comment: Damn, stupid me. :( Just for anyone's information: the error is gone when `ui` module is not specified as a `demoApp` dependency. Will try to investigate further, though...

Comment: I figured out why the content wasn't updating in my app, separate issue.  The error, however, still appears in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "$digest already in progress" error no longer shows up in the console.  I believe this issue was corrected in a newer version of AngularUI.

Answer (score 1):

I think that textarea isn't actually TinyMCE's working copy of the text being edited, the editor just dumps the text in there every once in a while. So for a clean solution, you'll probably have to use TinyMCE's [setContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.setContent) and [getContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.getContent) methods.

Comment: Yes!  This is the simplest and nimblest way!  I see all these intricate custom directives and third-party plugins that have to be integrated - often with bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach with angularJS, TinyMCE and Angular UI

Script Tags:

```
    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JQUERY UI -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- ANGULAR JS -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ANGULAR UI -->
    <script src="lib/angular-ui/angular-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- TINYMCE -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js"></script>
```

View:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="nota.fechaPub" ui-date ui-date-format required >
<textarea ui-tinymce="{theme:'simple'}" ng-model="nota.entradilla"></textarea>
...
<button ng-click="read()" class="btn btn-primary">Read</button>
```

Controller:

```
...
// Read the note function inside the controller
$scope.read= function () {
    var nota = $scope.nota;
    // In nota model I get two fields: entradilla (a text) and fechaPub ( a date)


}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Two way bind with AngularJS and TinyMCE using angular-ui-tinymce

Plnkr:  http://plnkr.co/edit/04AFkp?p=preview

Hope that helps :-)