# AngularJS with TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce

I am trying to get TinyMCE working with AngularJS and I found this [Integrating AngularJS and tinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953532/integrating-angularjs-and-tinymce) with the example: http://plnkr.co/edit/04AFkp?p=preview.

It works. But how can I have the TinyMCE to be customized? I tried with this, but it doesn't work.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.tinymce','MyController']);

angular.module("MyController",[]).controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.from_one = {
      from_one :'<strong>bold data in controller in from_one.js</strong>'
    };

    $scope.tinymceOptions = {
        height:500,
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | fullscreen",
        handle_event_callback: function (e) {
        // put logic here for keypress
        console.log("key pressed!");
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: `it doesn't work` is not a proper problem statement for technical troubleshooting

Comment: @charlietfl What I mean is putting that ``$scope.tinymceOptions`` has no effect at all. So, it doesn't work. No error message or anything.

Comment: works fine for me in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/c5oIcE?p=preview I just copied what you have above and connected it on the textrea markup. Delete a few toolbar options and watch it render without them

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for trying. But it actually doesn't really work. As you see, the option toolbar there has require 'fullscreen' button, but it doesn't appear on the TinyMCE.

Comment: ah but isn't that a plugin? I may be wrong

Comment: @charlietfl Actually that one is customizing the toolbar button.

Comment: but you have to register the plugins in the options also, not just in toolbar. look at source here http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php